# Using jitclass where class attribute is a list of class objects

Tags: python, numba

I am looking for a way to compile python class Node with `@jitclass`. The problem is with the attribute children which is a list of Nodes.

Thank you for the help.

```
from numba import jitclass, i4
from numba.typed import List

@jitclass([
    ('children', List[X]),
    ('row', i4),
    ('col', i4)
])
class Node:
    def __init__(self, board, row, col):
        self.children = [] # a list of Nodes
        self.row= row #integer
        self.col = col #integer
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this as you need a reference to Node to use it in a class, but you can't get a reference to it as Node doesn't exist yet.  The way I would tackle this is to put all Nodes in a flat hierarchy in a dictionary, then instead of putting the node itself into self.children, I would put a pointer to the node.  When you need the node, grab it from the dictionary.

Comment: This is a great answer. At the end I managed to do my own workaround.